# LLDB stop at breakpoint while expr function

Tags: xcode, lldb

for example

```
void foo()
{
   int a = 0;
   printf("%d",a);
}
```

I set a breakpoint at `foo` function, and then use `expr` to evaluate it, it just run the function, **didn't** stop at breakpoint.

```
(lldb) br set -n foo
(lldb) expr foo()
```

Is there a way to run any function/code while lldb breakpoint still working?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I found expr has a option --ignore-breakpoints

```
expr --ignore-breakpoints false -- foo()
```

will be working